# shell script which will move all executable files in the current directory to a seperate folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I trying to write shell script which will move all executable files in the current directory to a folder called "executables".

```
  1   for f in `ls`
  2    do
  3     if [ -x $f ]
  4      then
  5       cp -R $f ./executable/
  6     fi
  7    done
```

when  executed ,it says

```
cp: cannot copy a directory, 'executable', into itself, './executable/executable'.
```

so how i avoid checking the 'executable' folder in the if condition.
 or there is any other perfect solution for this.

Comment: Try using the `find` utility for such things. It offers a few file handling specific  features instead of string based operation. For example you can limit the search to ordinary files.

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't parse the output of `ls`.
2. Most directories have the executable bit set.
3. `cp` is copying, `mv` is moving.

Adapting your script:

```
for f in *; do
  if [ -f "$f" ] && [ -x "$f" ]; then
    mv "$f" executables/
  fi
done
```

With GNU `find`:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm +a=x -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} executables/
```